# Putting json data into table

Tags: php, html, json, curl

So i have a json file that is inputting it into a table. Now i want to post the price to but i have no idea how

This is my json:

```
    {
   "total": 1,
   "items": [
      {
         "icon": "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4173_obj_sprite.gif?id=11230",
         "icon_large": "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4173_obj_big.gif?id=11230",
         "id": 11230,
         "type": "Ammo",
         "typeIcon": "http://www.runescape.com/img/categories/Ammo",
         "name": "Dragon dart",
         "description": "A deadly throwing dart with a dragon tip.",
         "current": {
            "trend": "neutral",
            "price": 184
         },
         "today": {
            "trend": "neutral",
            "price": 0
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Now i have it working that is post the items icon id type and name. But i also want the current price being posted. I have tried it with the following :

```
    foreach($arr['current'] as $val2){
    echo '<td>'. htmlspecialchars($val2['price']) .'</td></tr>';          

}
```

with getting the following error :

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   on line 28

This is my script for getting the data:

```
    <?php
//check if you have curl loaded
if(!function_exists("curl_init")) die("cURL extension is not installed");

$url = 'http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/items.json?category=1&alpha=d&page=1';

$ch=curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$r=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$arr = json_decode($r,true);
echo "<table>";
foreach($arr['items'] as $val)
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$val['id'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'. htmlspecialchars($val['type']) .'</td>';
    echo '<td>'. htmlspecialchars($val['name']) .'</td>';
    echo '<td><img src='. $val['icon'].'></td>'; 

}
foreach($arr['current'] as $val2){
    echo '<td>'. htmlspecialchars($val2['price']) .'</td></tr>';          

}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

So my question : How do i also post the current price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is better written as

```
 echo '<td>'. htmlspecialchars($val['current']['price']) .'</td></tr>';
```

your were trying to iterate `$arr` which is the outter array which doesn't contain a element called `current`

Answer (score 0):

If the attributes inside current has not always returning the same key, you can use this:

```
if(!function_exists("curl_init")) die("cURL extension is not installed");

$url = 'http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/items.json?category=1&alpha=d&page=1';

$ch=curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$r=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$arr = json_decode($r,true);

echo "<table border='1'>";
foreach($arr['items'] as $val)
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$val['id'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'. htmlspecialchars($val['type']) .'</td>';
    echo '<td>'. htmlspecialchars($val['name']) .'</td>';
    echo '<td><img src='. $val['icon'].'></td>';
    foreach($val['current'] as $v){
        echo '<td>'. htmlspecialchars($v) .'</td>';
    }
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$json_str='   {
   "total": 1,
   "items": [
      {
         "icon": "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4173_obj_sprite.gif?id=11230",
         "icon_large": "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4173_obj_big.gif?id=11230",
         "id": 11230,
         "type": "Ammo",
         "typeIcon": "http://www.runescape.com/img/categories/Ammo",
         "name": "Dragon dart",
         "description": "A deadly throwing dart with a dragon tip.",
         "current": {
            "trend": "neutral",
            "price": 184
         },
         "today": {
            "trend": "neutral",
            "price": 0
         }
      }
   ]
}';
$arr = json_decode($json_str,true);
// this $arr contains array with-in array so there is no direct access to 
// 'Price' its either inside current or today so access  them accordingly like 
$arr['current']['price'];
//or
$arr['today']['price'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

First check if the array is empty or not. If the array is empty it will through error because you are passing an associative array and in the first loop there is no close for tr tag.

```
if(!empty($arr))
{
     //for loop
}
else
{
    echo "Array empty";
}
```